# Принципы современной русской орфографии

Tags: морфология

Написание всех слов русского языка подчинено нескольким принципам: фонетическому, морфологическому, традиционному, дифференцированному.
Написание каких слов подчиняется традиционному принципу?

Морфологический принцип.
Рожь, 
Прячь.
Сыграть ( приставка с всегда звучит пишется одинакова, потому что в сильной позиции (перед гласными, сонорными и [в]) она звучит как [сі:]
Скрипка

Традиционный принцип
Ползаешь.
Удирать
Балл 
Дифференцированный
ожёг
балл

рожь (– женского рода, рогач – мужского (в данных случаях ь мягкости не обозначает, так как [ж] всегда твердый).

Фонетический принцип

Какое слово можно отнести к фонетическому принципу? Не вижу слова, которое подподало бы под фонетический принцип.

Comment: На вопросы по принципам письма я не отвечаю, так как не совсем понимаю их учебную трактовку. Но в данном случае могу предположить, что к фонетическому принципу относится слово "сыграть"  (отражение на письме чередования Ы/И в  корне).

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту, но он в тоже время относится и к морфологическому.

Comment: Но в правилах сказано: . Написание ы вместо начального и (по произношению) в корне после приставок2, оканчивающихся на твердый согласный: безыскусственный, изысканный, безыдейный, предыюльский и т.

Comment: Но ведь здесь нет приставки на согласную.

Comment: А приставка С разве не на согласную?

Comment: Но там имеются в виду такие приставки, как без, пред. Т. е. которые состоят из нескольких букв.

Comment: Нет разницы, здесь главное, что звук твердый, после него мы слышим звук Ы и пишем букву Ы. Правило относится к этой приставке тоже.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!